# in gwt, how to export a ArrayList<String> and prompt a save dialog for user download?

Tags: gwt, servlets, export

I try to use GWT-RPC to call servlet to export the data, to simplify the case, I just try to hardcode the output text first, with the following code in the RemoteServiceServlet

```
public void exportHistory(ArrayList<String> sqlHistory){
    this.sqlHistory = sqlHistory;
    try {
        HttpServletResponse res = this.getThreadLocalResponse();
        res.setContentType("text/plain");
        res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=history.txt");
        ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        out.println("test1");
        out.println("test2");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it return onFailure(Throwable caught) in the asyncCallback, the caught is InvocationException.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json` object for passing your list.